# Identify if an image is blurred (preferred without OpenCV)

Tags: ios, swift, image, avcapturesession

Just completed building a camera using `AVCaptureSession` for scanning documents on iPhone, I am looking for away to determine if the captured image is in good quality and not blurred.
I saw many solutions using OpenCV and I am looking for an other options.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

First of all, interesting question, made me do some research to figure out stuff myself. In general, [Analysis of focus measure operators for shape-from-focus](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0031320312004736) is a great research paper, talking about a few methods (36 to be precise) on how to get measure of blurriness in an image, from simple/straightforward ones to more complex ones.

I have done myself some basic laplacian operation on one channel of the image (essentially 2nd derivative of the pixels) to measure the blurriness, which worked quite well for me. Once you convolve the channel with the laplacian operator, the variance of this laplacian image is a good estimate of the blurriness. The assumption here is that if an image contains *high variance* then there is a wide spread of responses, both edge-like and non-edge like, representative of a normal, in-focus image. But if there is *very low variance*, then there is a tiny spread of responses, indicating there are very little edges in the image. As we know, the more an image is blurred, the less edges there are. The trick here is to find an apt threshold for the variance to be high/low, which I guess you can ascertain by running it on your dataset.

Courtesy: [Blog](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/07/blur-detection-with-opencv/)

PS. Although the blog I reference here mentions "OpenCV", the methods can be implemented as you want if you understand the concept and hence I started the answer with the [research paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0031320312004736).